# Badge Addition: New Reputation high score in a day

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I would like to suggest a new badge.  I think there should be a badge (silver or bronze) that is earned every time a user reaches a their new high score of reputation gain in a single day.

Maybe it could be awarded only if the new high score is above 200 rep . . .

What do the moderators think of this idea?

Comment: Define "a new high score".  Is it a personal high score or a site-wide high score?

Answer (score 17):

Why? There's already the Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary badges.

Do I really need a badge because I got 5 reputation on day 1, 10 reputation on day 2, 11 reputation on day 3... ?

Badges are supposed to reward some sort of behavior, not because you got a personal high score for the day.  The privileges that come with the reputation, and the reputation itself should be reward enough.

Comment: It would get a lot harder.  I've got 227 rep today.  Next time I beat that, I should get a badge.

Comment: Again, **why**?

Comment: Just for further motivation.

Comment: @Godisgood: what it motivates is hitting the next high score *just one point higher* than the previous time, to maximise the badge count. Is that really what we want?

Comment: @Godisgood: a badge hunter won't go *I'll hit my next target 100 points more than last*. They'll go *If I get 10 one day, then 11 the next, then 12, I'll get more badges*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, check the middle line in my edit.

Comment: I hereby award you the never-before-awarded "LittleBobbyTables Good-job-at-getting-a-personal-high-score-at-Stack-Overflow Intangible Reward"™.  Come back when you get 228 in a day.  Go get 'em, tiger!

Comment: @Godisgood: so you get it at 201, then 202, then 203. You already got the mortarboard the first time, what good comes out of getting more of these?

Comment: I was just an idea.  Sorry for asking, people.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, would you remove your answer so I can delete this question?

Comment: @Godisgood - Votes on Meta are just a sign of who agrees with the *idea* of the post.  So far, 14 people think your proposal should not be implemented.  It does not mean anything negative towards you personally.

Comment: Ok.  So it's not bad that I got -14 votes.  That WOULD be bad on the main site, @iCodez.  Right?

Comment: Don't ask users to delete their answers/contributions. **That is bad.**

Comment: @Godisgood Correct, that would be bad on the main site because you're either asking a bad question, or providing an unhelpful answer. On meta, you're simply having a discussion about SO, not imparting development knowledge. No harm, no foul. Privileges are on SO Meta are still tied to your main site rep score.